# Creating a scatterplot to show correlation

Tags: r

I am trying to create a scatterplot showing the correlation between humidity and rainfall using my large data set. However, I think the correlation would be better if I did it using the average humidity and sum of rainfall in a month in a particular location, as right now the daily data points for rainfall are at zero as most days it doesn't rain.

[image: this is the current scatter plot I have now]

The issue is that I'm unsure as to how to sum the values of rain over the days specifically for one year and one month, and similarly find the average of humidity. And then by doing this get two corresponding data points (average humidity in month: sum of rainfall in month) to use in scatterplot

Small example of data set: last columns is humidity and 2nd last rainfall, first column is date.

[image: img]

Thanks, any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: Please don't post code or data as images. Use plain text so other users can copy/paste. You can use `dput()` and/or `head()` for data, code can just be indented by 4 spaces.

Answer (score 0):

Without data to work with, I would recommend grouping by months using the `dplyr` package's `group_by()` function to group by months and then using `summarize()` to calculate mean and sum humidity values.

---

**Edit**: I tracked down rainfall and 3 PM relative humidity data for the past 13 months on the Australian Government's Bureau of Meteorology website.

I used the `data.table` and `tidyverse` packages for data ingestion and data sanitization, respectively. Here's the code I used:

```
library(data.table)
library(tidyverse)
df <- as_tibble(fread('IDCJDW2125.csv'))
df <- add_column(df, Month = format(as.Date(df$Date), '%B %Y'), .after = 'Date') %>%
  group_by(Month) %>%
  summarize(sum(`Rainfall (mm)`), mean(`3pm relative humidity (%)`))
colnames(df)[2:3] <- c('Total Rainfall (mm)', 'Average 3 PM Relative Humidity (%)')
ggplot(df, aes(x = `Total Rainfall (mm)`, y = `Average 3 PM Relative Humidity (%)`)) +
  geom_point()
```

Here's what the data looks like:

```
# A tibble: 6 x 21
  Date  `Minimum temper~ `Maximum temper~ `Rainfall (mm)` `Evaporation (m~ `Sunshine (hour~ `Direction of m~ `Speed of maxim~ `Time of maximu~ `9am Temperatur~
  <chr>            <dbl>            <dbl>           <dbl>            <dbl>            <dbl> <chr>                       <int> <chr>                       <dbl>
1 2018~              9.2             21.4               0              4                9.6 WSW                            41 15:42                        15.7
2 2018~              9.1             19                 0              5.2              7.9 ENE                            33 14:48                        14.1
3 2018~              9.4             23.4               0              2                9.5 WNW                            57 23:07                        15  
4 2018~             11.3             20.7               0              5.2              8.6 WNW                            54 9:56                         15.5
5 2018~              6.9             20.9               0              5.6             10.3 NE                             41 16:38                        12.6
6 2018~             11.9             19.7               0              4                4   NW                             69 15:16                        13.6
# ... with 11 more variables: `9am relative humidity (%)` <int>, `9am cloud amount (oktas)` <int>, `9am wind direction` <chr>, `9am wind speed (km/h)` <int>, `9am
#   MSL pressure (hPa)` <dbl>, `3pm Temperature (°C)` <dbl>, `3pm relative humidity (%)` <int>, `3pm cloud amount (oktas)` <int>, `3pm wind direction` <chr>, `3pm
#   wind speed (km/h)` <chr>, `3pm MSL pressure (hPa)` <dbl>
```

While the correlation between the average 3 PM relative humidity and the total rainfall per month is not strong, the positive relationship is much more noticeable.

[image]

Comment: Thanks you so much for the fantastic reply, i'm in the process of getting the new packages, however how would i go about adding a regression line to the scatter plot?